# How to determine the axis of a polaroid?

Tags: visible-light, polarization

I have found a polaroid from an old LCD device. It is rectangular in shape and does not have any markings on it. I wanted to somehow determine its axis, maybe not exact. I have tried to use it in front of a TV and phone screen, but I can't understand anything from that. I also know about polarised blue sky, but I don't know how it can help. So can anyone please suggest a way to know it (approximate) axis.

Comment: Do you have another polaroid of known orientation?

Comment: @probably_someone i dont have another, but i have a digital watch shows time in one orientation but not in other, can it work, somehow?

Comment: @probably_someone even if i had one more, can this help in someway?

Comment: If you place a polaroid of unknown orientation over one with known orientation, and shine a light through them, the light will appear brightest when the axes are oriented the same direction (assuming both polaroids are linearly polarizing - if either or both use circular polarization, this won't work).

Comment: @probably_someone it is much more ridiculous than that, it is a rectangle with its axis on angle bisector of one of its angle

Comment: @probably_someone i.e. at 45° from one of its side, i confirmed it by fliping it against the watch

Comment: well, this also means that there are only two possibilities of axis

Comment: How do you know the orientation of the polarization of the watch screen?

Comment: @probably_someone i dont know, only i know when they match and when they don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polarized light results from reflection on transparent objects.   Find a
plate of glass, and look at a reflection in it, at about 45 degrees.   The orientation 
of the polarizer that dims the reflection the most, is with the polarization
axis of the polarizer antiparallel to the plate ( most nearly aligned with the
perpendicular to the surface).

This is most effective at Brewster's angle, and is the basis of devices
like sugar refractometers for beer-making.

Alternately, if you can find a polarizer filter for a camera, there's usually a mark
indicating the axis orientation for that filter; when your polarizer is
in front of that filter and at right angles to its polarization, the
view from behind (camera-side) of the sandwich will be dark.

Comment: Well, this is super cool. I can actually see it happening. Thanx for help :)

Comment: does the word antiparallel mean perpendicular here, because dictionary meaning is parallel but opposite, but the next line says "most nearly aligned with the perpendicular to the surface", that is confusing me a bit

Comment: @PranshuKhandal   I intended 'antiparallel' to mean the axis of the polarizer that is not parallel to the plane of the reflector.   So, nonparallel to plane or near-perpendicular to plane are both intended.    The film needn't be oriented so that any axis in the film plane is truly perpendicular to the reflector plane.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know answer by @Whit3rd is best, but for reference, which I think I found by some study:

On a clear day, put your polaroid in front of blue sky, a little bit away from the Sun. Rotate the polaroid in such a position such that brightness of sky is least. And now, the line from Sun to the polaroid becomes the axis.

For example, if Sun is on the head and you are looking in front, with sky at its minimum brightness, the vertical will be the axis.